# Thank you for + ing or thank you for having + past participle

Tags: tense, idioms, gerunds, past-participles

I'm wondering if there is a difference between the following forms:

1. Thank you **for downloading** the file *(for + ing)*
2. Thank you **for having downloaded** the file *(for + having + past participle)*

Both looks correct. I usually use form 1 if someone has just downloaded the file. I'd rather use form 2 if that happened in the past. Not sure about such assumptions. I really appreciate any hints.

Comment: Both are correct, but **1** is more idiomatic in both situations you mention IMO.

Comment: When I was a child, I was taught to be polite on leaving somewhere I had been a guest, and say 'Thank you for having me'. I think that I would have been in several kinds of trouble if I had said to a friend's mother 'Thank you for having had me'.

Comment: Thanks. To summarize, the bottom line seems: "use _thank you for + ing_ regardless of when it happened"